# How to export bot registration's analytics

Tags: botframework, powerbi, azure-application-insights

Follow the steps here (https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/bot-service/bot-service-manage-analytics?view=azure-bot-service-4.0), I can check bot analytics. I think these data are from Azure application insight. But how could I export them using powerBI, or any other tools? I need the same charts.

By the way, I'm using botframework V3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

First, I would recommend reading [this blog article](https://blog.botframework.com/2019/03/21/bot-analytics-behind-the-scenes/) as it shows a bit of how the bot analytics are structured and might give insight into what you might want to query for.

Once you have your query up and returning the correct data that you want in Applications Insights Logs(Analytics), you can query that in PowerBI by exporting the M language script from Logs and then opening that in PowerBI which will then query the data you need. Please view how to do that step [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/export-power-bi#export-analytics-queries).